# Force IntelliJ to activate SQL intellisence

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ Idea activates intellisence on SQL queries when recognizes that a string is used to query DB.
In my case a created a custom annotation

```
@ManualSql(
        sqlList="select * from zsrb_progetto_gruppo_disegno where 1=1",
        sqlCount = "select count(*) from zsrb_progetto_gruppo_disegno where 1=1"
)
```

But the IDE doesn't recognize it as SQL statement therefore does not activate SQL intellisence.
Is there a way to force the IDE to activate SQL intellisence in user defined situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `//language=SQL` comment before the statement:

```java
@ManualSql(
        //language=SQL
        sqlList = "select * from zsrb_progetto_gruppo_disegno where 1=1",
        //language=SQL
        sqlCount = "select count(*) from zsrb_progetto_gruppo_disegno where 1=1"
)
```

After that, you can configure SQL dialect and data sources inside the strings.